# MySQL : getting top 100 records for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called: `consultant_project_score` which has the following fields `id`, `project_id`,  `final_score`. I want to generate a query which displays top 100 final_score for each project_id.  I am using `MySQL workbench 6.3` and I am not able to use any `create/insert` statements. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: what's error you are getting?? what you have tried ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested,but it should work.The trick is to generate a row number for each project

```
select id, project_id, final_score
from 
(select id, project_id, final_score,
      @rn:= if(@project_id= project_id, @rn+ 1, 1) as rn,
      @project_id:= project_id as pi
  from t,(SELECT @rn:=0) b
  order by project_id, final_score desc) x 
where x.rn<= 100;
```

Comment: I tried your query, I assume that 't' stands for consultant_project_score. Anyway it generated around 9milion records while I only have around 2000 projects in my DB, so it should have been around 200.000 records

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. The inner query will generate rank group by `project_id` and then outer query will filter the top 100 results.

Note: It will not work if you have similar combination of project_id and score. Created this fiddle to get 2 ranks.

**<kbd>http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e94d5/1</kbd>**

```
SELECT id1,
       project_id,
       final_score
FROM
  (SELECT max(t1.id) AS id1,
          t1.project_id,
          t1.final_score,
          count(*) AS rnk
   FROM consultant_project_score t1
   INNER JOIN consultant_project_score t2 ON t1.project_id=t2.project_id
   WHERE t1.final_score<=t2.final_score
   GROUP BY t1.project_id,
            t1.final_score) t
WHERE rnk<=100
```

Comment: I'm trying out your query. It's been running for about 10 min now.

Comment: The query will be slow as we are doing self join with group by. In MYSql, there are no `rank over partition by` else the query would be faster.

You can try removing `max(t1.id)` from select clause. Also is possible, index `project_id` and `final_score`.

Answer (score 0):

This one is without `Group BY` and uses the concept of `self join` . This should give you correct output

**SQL**

```
   SELECT cps2.id, cps2.project_id,  cps2.final_score FROM 
                    (  SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM  consultant_project_score ) cps1 
                     JOIN  consultant_project_score cps2
                                            ON cps2.id  IN ( SELECT cps3.id FROM consultant_project_score cps3 
                            WHERE cps3.project_id = cps1.projectid  
                             ORDER BY cps3.final_score  DESC LIMIT 100) 
                    ORDER BY cps2.project_id ,cps2.final_score DESC
```

Comment: Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' 0.000 sec